# Intellij Debugger Display behavior

Tags: java, intellij-idea, debuggervisualizer

I am curious about how Intellij Debugger decides what to display for Java. Using below code as an example.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("A", "ValA");
        map.put("B", "ValB");
        Collection values = map.values();
        System.out.println(values);
    }
}
```

When I called `map.values()`, it returned a `Collection` type. Looking into code inside `HashMap` class, we can see `values` method actually return a final class called `Values` which extends `AbstractCollection` class, with an empty constructor inside `AbstractCollection` class, as shown below

```
protected AbstractCollection() {
}
```

However, if I added breakpoint to `System.out.println` line, the Intellij debugger displays `values` variable like below (circled in red).How does the debugger get the data "ValA", "ValB" from `Values` class? Is the debugger have tailored-made implementation for each default Java Classes to display proper values?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit the breakpoint on the line of `Sysytem.out.println()`, it proves that the code of your current thread has been completely executed before this line, and all your values have been saved in the Collection, so idea can recognize .

Comment: so the debugger is tailer made for each Java Class to get proper data?

Comment: @HKIT Because idea can obtain data that has been compiled or executed by jvm when each java program is running, there is no problem with your understanding. idea is just a tool, but when you hit a breakpoint, idea can Block the current program here so that you can clearly see the fields that have been assigned data.